# How to iterate over 2 arrays inside a for loop in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, for-loop

I am working on a script that should install hotfixes on environments depending on the usage type of the environment and the release date. For this, I need to check the type of environment and then the release date of the hotfix. If the environment's usage type is `prod` and `time1` number of seconds have passed since the release of the hotfix, then install the hotfix.

By reading similar questions on the site, I came up with this.

```
u=( prod test dev)
t=( time2 time2 time3 )

# where t represents the number of seconds that must pass after the release date in order for the hotfix to be installed

for ((i=0;i<${#u[@]};i++))
do
    if ($usage_type=${u[i]} && $hf_release_date -ge $current_time+${t[i]}); then install_hotfix; fi 
done
```

Would the above code work as intended?

EDIT:

I tried fixing the syntax, but I am still missing something:

```
u=( prod test dev)
t=( time2 time2 time3 )

# where t represents the number of seconds that must pass after the release date in order for the hotfix to be installed

for ((i=0;i<${#u[@]};i++))
do
    if [[ "$usage_type" == "${u[i]}" ]] && [[ "$hf_release_date" -ge "$current_time"+"${t[i]}" ]]; then install_hotfix; fi 
done
```

Comment: Try https://shellcheck.net

Comment: It is up to you to say if your code works, and if not, what the problem is. In your snippet, you should include the instructions computing the value of the variables `$hf_release_date` and `$current_time`.

Comment: Anyway, the way to iterate over the arrays seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is "how to iterate over two arrays", you can check that that part of your code is correct by running next snippet:

```sh
u=( prod test dev)
t=( time2 time2 time3 )

for ((i=0;i<${#u[@]};i++)) 
  do echo "u[$i] = ${u[i]}, t[$i] = ${t[i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
u[0] = prod, t[0] = time2
u[1] = test, t[1] = time2
u[2] = dev, t[2] = time3
```